How to label outliers on a pandas scatter plot
I want to label a few outliers on a volcano plot I have created. I had the idea to first create a df that consists only of the largest 3 values (aka my outliers) for my column of interest, and then use this df to label my volcano plot. I have been able to get the labels onto my plot, however, because my plot is using the -log10 of my y axis, I am having trouble getting my labels at the appropriate height. If I use the raw values from my y axis column, the labels all bunch together at the bottom of the graph. When I try to use the -log10 values of my y axis, I get an error.
Most people in my field use adobe to label outliers after making their plots, but I would really like to find a way to label my points using python.
Example table, code, and error below.
#example df

data = {'log2FoldChange': [15, 16, 2, 3],
        'pvalue': [0.0000005, 0.00006, 0.7, 0.9],
        'padj': [0.0008, 0.005, 0.0008, 0.0007],
        'gene_name': ['gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3', 'gene4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)

#creating a subset of my df that only highlights the 3 genes with the highest log2foldchange

outliersx = df.nlargest(3, 'log2FoldChange')

#plotting volcano plot. NOTE: y axis is the -log10 of pvalue. 

plt.scatter(x=df2['log2FoldChange'],y=df2['pvalue'].apply(lambda x:-np.log10(x)),s=1)
#dash marks 
plt.axvline(0.6,color="grey",linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(-0.6,color="grey",linestyle="--")
plt.axhline(1.3,color="grey",linestyle="--")
#highlighting significantly down regulated genes
down = df2[(df2['log2FoldChange']<=-0.6)&(df2['pvalue']<=0.05)]
plt.scatter(x=down['log2FoldChange'],y=down['pvalue'].apply(lambda x:-np.log10(x)),s=3,label="Down-regulated",color="blue")
#highlighting significantly upregulated genes
up = df2[(df2['log2FoldChange']>=0.6)&(df2['pvalue']<=0.05)]
plt.scatter(x=up['log2FoldChange'],y=up['pvalue'].apply(lambda x:-np.log10(x)),s=3,label="Up-regulated",color="red")

plt.xlabel("logFC")
plt.ylabel("-logFDR")

#axis labels
plt.xlabel("log2foldchange")
plt.ylabel("-log10(pvalue)")

#Here I am using ax.annotate to try and annotate the three largest log2foldchange data points in my data. 

outliersx[['log2FoldChange','pvalue','gene_name']].apply(lambda row: ax.text(*row),axis=1);



I realized that all of my labels were clustering at the bottom because I was using the raw pvalue instead of the -log10 pvalue as the coordinate for my labels. Thus I next tried to use the -log10 of the pvalues by applying the following code, but I got an error.
outliersx[['log2FoldChange',outliersx['pvalue'].apply(lambda x:-np.log10(x)),'gene_name']].apply(lambda row: ax.text(*row),axis=1);

#TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

I am a bit confused as to why I am getting that error and I would appreciate any guidance on how I can use the -log10 of the pvalue column as a y coordinate for where my labels should be applied.

Simplest way is to assign the transformed pvalue

outliersx[['log2FoldChange', 'pvalue', 'gene_name']].assign(pvalue=-np.log10(outliersx['pvalue'])).apply(lambda row: plt.gca().text(*row), axis=1) https://i.sstatic.net/AJYBAjB8.png

I would start off just like you did and add the annotation afterwards:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'log2FoldChange': [15, 16, 2, 3],
        'pvalue': [0.0000005, 0.00006, 0.7, 0.9],
        'padj': [0.0008, 0.005, 0.0008, 0.0007],
        'gene_name': ['gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3', 'gene4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

plt.scatter(df['log2FoldChange'], -np.log10(df['pvalue']), s=10, color='grey')

down = df[(df['log2FoldChange'] <= -0.6) & (df['pvalue'] <= 0.05)]
up = df[(df['log2FoldChange'] >= 0.6) & (df['pvalue'] <= 0.05)]

plt.scatter(down['log2FoldChange'], -np.log10(down['pvalue']), s=30, color='blue', label="Down-regulated")
plt.scatter(up['log2FoldChange'], -np.log10(up['pvalue']), s=30, color='red', label="Up-regulated")

plt.axvline(x=0.6, color="grey", linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(x=-0.6, color="grey", linestyle="--")
plt.axhline(y=-np.log10(0.05), color="grey", linestyle="--")

plt.xlabel("log2FoldChange")
plt.ylabel("-log10(pvalue)")
plt.title("Volcano Plot")
plt.legend()


outliers = df.nlargest(3, 'log2FoldChange')

for index, row in outliers.iterrows():
    plt.text(row['log2FoldChange'], -np.log10(row['pvalue']), row['gene_name'], fontsize=9, ha='right')


giving

